# Pycharm_Why the outcome is different when I run the code with normal mode and debug mode?

Tags: python, multithreading, pycharm

I am learning about thread and copied an example code from the book.

The code is exactly the same but the outcome is different according to which way the the code is launched in Pycharm.

Here is my code:

```
import threading

g_count = 0

def thread_main():
    global g_count
    for i in range(100000):
        g_count += 1

threads = []

for i in range(50):
    th = threading.Thread(target=thread_main)
    threads.append(th)

for th in threads:
    th.start()

for th in threads:
    th.join()

print("g_count = {:,}".format(g_count))
```

1. When I run the code with 'Run' (ctrl+shift+F10)

the outcome is always **5,000,000**, which is not expected.

2. When I run the code with 'debug' (alt+shift+F10)

the outcome is always different as expected.

How come 'run' mode always prints **5,000,000** in this case?

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem when I run it - are you sure the code above is exactly the same as you're using in PyCharm?

Comment: @tda yes. doesn't your result show 5,000,000 everytime?

Comment: Nope - I get a different result every time when running normally? Have you tried running in a different IDE/Jupyter notebook/python script from command line?